# React and Wordpress under same Domain with NGINX

Tags: wordpress

I have some content in WordPress for pages with static content or Marketing landing pages. We decided to go on this way because of reasons...

So for doing that I have the configuration below in NGINX

```
server {
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/webapp;
        index index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri /index.html;

        location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff)$ {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/webapp.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/webapp.error.log;

    }

    # Alias for discover when is Wordpress related content
    location /discover/ {

        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        root /var/www/wordpress;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress.error.log;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index            index.php;
            fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            include                  fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

    }

}
```

Sadly this is not working, it's always rendering or try to render the react app even when I go to mydomain.com/discover/ or /discover/something

I configured WordPress URL to mydomain.com/discover in the WP Configuration.

The error for this configuration is

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client:
```

If I move the PHP extension file configuration outside of /discover I remove the FastCGI Primary script unknown error but I still NGINX resolve everything to the react app.

Some I'm quite new with NGINX I've been using Apache my whole so might be a really noob error, but it's killing already.

I tried moving things around even as default but similar errors.

Any help or guide will help me.

Comment: BTW I have the WordPress project configured in the same server under other domain and works fine

Comment: Is WordPress installed under `/var/www/wordpress/` or `/var/www/wordpress/discover/`?

Comment: /var/www/wordpress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access a path like `/var/www/wordpress/` with a URI like `/discover/`, you will need to use `alias` rather than `root`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

For example:

```
location ^~ /discover {
    alias /var/www/wordpress;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress.error.log;

    index index.php;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /discover/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include       fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

The `location` value and the `alias` value should either both end with a `/` or neither end with a `/`.

Note that when using `alias`, `$request_filename` should be used to find the path to the filename.

There is a [long standing bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) related to using `alias` and `try_files` together, which is why these blocks use the `if` directive instead. Note [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of the `if` directive.

Comment: I made a copy and paste and work perfectly, thank you for the explanation and the solution.